# Add async attribute to iframe google maps

Tags: google

I got an iframe to insert googlemap on.my site. but I would need to give it the async attribute.  hoping it can be done.

how can I do? the idea was to put the code in a wrapper module or a custom module, but I don't know how to add the async.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the Joomla Web Asset Manager, described [here](https://manual.joomla.org/docs/general-concepts/web-asset-manager).

You define your javascript dependency in a `joomla.asset.json` file, and include your async attribute that way:

```
"attributes": {
    "async": true
  }
```

You should put this file and the javascript file inside the /media folder via your module installation xml file, eg:

```
<media destination="mod_mymodule" folder="media">
    <filename>joomla.asset.json</filename>
    <folder>js</folder>
</media>
```

If you're using a custom module then you'll need to tell Joomla to load that `joomla.asset.json` file, as it won't do it automatically. As described on that same page you can do:

```
$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wr = $wa->getRegistry();
$wr->addRegistryFile('relative/path/to/your/joomla.asset.json');
// eg $wr->addRegistryFile('media/mod_mymodule/joomla.asset.json');
```

If you're not familiar with the web asset manager then [this video](https://youtu.be/QCtfJLsArF4) might help.

If you really want to use the old way of adding javascript then you can include in your module code:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$document = Factory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("...demo.js", array(), array('async'=>'async'));
```

as described in [Adding JavaScript and CSS to the page](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page).